# SSH working by IP but by name

Tags: ssh

**General context:**

I have a server with several LXD containers and having an HAPROXY on top to redirect traffic to good container regarding url given.

The pointed container is gitlab.

**Main server**

Port 22 is open

```
server# iptables -L -n |grep 22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22

server# netstat -plnt | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2536/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2536/sshd
```

**Gitlab server configuration**

```
gitlab# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       gitlab.pub-domain.com gitlab
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       s-302-gitlab # machine name
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

gitlab# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search pub-domain.com
search priv-domain.ovh
nameserver 8.8.8.8

# netstat -tulpn | grep 22
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9229          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      583/gitlab-workhors 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5094/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      5094/ssh
```

**Ping everything**

Launched in gitlab containers and works:

```
gitlab# # ssh -T https://git@gitlab.pub-domain.com
https://git@pub-domain.com's password:
gitlab# ssh -T https://git@192.168.3.200
https://git@192.168.3.200's password:
```

Now go to another machine (let's say server to make it simple) and ping :

```
server# ping pub-domain.com
PING pub-domain.com (31.7.xx.yy) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 31.7.xx.yy (31.7.xx.yy): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.588 ms
--- pub-domain.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms

server# ping gitlab.pub-domain.com
PING pub-domain.com (31.7.xx.yy) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 31.7.xx.yy (31.7.xx.yy): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.588 ms
--- pub-domain.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

**SSH**

```
server# ssh git@s-302-gitlab
ssh: connect to host s-302-gitlab port 22: Connection refused
server# ssh -T https://git@gitlab.pub-domain.com
ssh: connect to host gitlab.pub-domain.com port 22: Connection refused
server# ssh -T git@192.168.3.200
The authenticity of host '192.168.3.200 (192.168.3.200)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Pe2vY/8GyG3o6ZkDErTN8Ko+k9veJA9S4wnHvQXSYJk.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Any idea why I can connect only using IP and not the domain/URL?

**Responding to comments**

```
# dig +short s-302-gitlab
# dig +short gitlab.pub-domain.com
pub-domain.com.
31.7.xx.yy
```

Thanks,

Comment: On `server`, what's the output of `dig +short s-302-gitlab`? Try the same for `gitlab.pub-domain.com`.

Comment: @digijay : first one nothing, second one pub-domain and external IP. See my edit in original post.

Comment: You add the `-v` option to your ssh call multiple times to increase verbosity. Then ssh will tell, more specifically, what connection was refused. By the way, Your user name is probably a mistake. Usually `https://` would denote a connection that uses HTTP, whereas ssh user names generally do not contain slashes or colons.

Comment: `s-302-gitlab` is defined in your `/etc/hosts` file. What IP address did you expect it to have? Because you immediately then tried to ssh to `192.168.3.200` which is not the same IP address.